# Can I remove pipenv cache folder? How to safely do it

Tags: python, delete-file, pipenv

while using my pipenv virtual environment, I found a huge folder full of cache, I want to know:

1. Can I delete it?
2. If yes, how to delete it
3. What consequences could have deleting it

Route: `home/cache/pipenv`

[image: Delete]

Comment: Yes you can remove cache folder

Answer (score 34):

While simply deleting the Cache subfolder works fine, using `pipenv lock --clear` deletes the cache for your current project only. If you properly want to get rid of all the somewhen collected data, use

```
pipenv --clear
```

instead. You'll see `Clearing caches ...` and the cache folder disappears. According to the [documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/diagnose/) it is usually in one of the following locations:

```
~/Library/Caches/pipenv (macOS)
%LOCALAPPDATA%\pipenv\pipenv\Cache (Windows)
~/.cache/pipenv (other operating systems)
```

Comment: FWIW I found the `pipenv --clear` option not to work, although it is clearly listed in the documentation so I'm not sure what was going on.

Comment: The documentation says `pipenv --clear` clears the `pip` cache also. That seems really bad, since I only occasionally have to use `pipenv`, and want my `pip` cache to stay intact. (https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/)

Comment: It needs to be e.g. `pipenv --clear install` as `--clear` by itself does't do anything.

Comment: @Radzor That's not true. After `pipenv --clear` you'll get `Clearing caches ...` and afterwards the cache folder is gone. However, depending on your OS, you'll find the cache folder in different locations.

Comment: I just updated to the most recent version of `pipenv` and `pipenv --clear` just shows the command usage

Answer (score 3):

Caches are meant to be temporary so you can always clear them. With pipenv you can call `pipenv lock --clear`, or maybe the dirtier way by just deleting the folder. Seems like a lot of people have [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3655) with bloated pipenv caches. The downside to clearing the cache is that it will take longer for pipenv to download or install packages because it cannot quickly search for previously used versions in the cache folder.

Comment: Note that `pipenv lock --clear` also locks the requirements, which is an undesired artifact if all you want is to clear the cache. For this purpose, use `pipenv --clear` as suggested below.